# Cell Broadcasts for LG lucid with android 4.0.4

Tags: cell-broadcast

I've looked at the wikipedia article and it is very informative.  But my husband had a Verizon LG Lucid with Android 4.0.4.  NO WHERE can I find a way to adjust the cell broadcasts!  I have a Samsung Galaxy and there is a page to check what kind of emergencies to receive notifications.  I can turn any/all of them off.  What about the LUCID??

Comment: Anna, my LG Optimus 4X has a separate app for that which came pre-installed ("Cell Info"). Maybe your LG device has it as well? If not, you could check the tag-wiki of 'cell-broadcast' (simply hover your mouse over the tag for additional links; click it to see all questions tagged with it).

Answer (score 0):

My LG Optimus 5 (E455 and E450) also has a pre-installed application called cell broadcast, with CB enabled. I disabled it.